# Rabbit MQ Ctl - connection to channel mapping

Tags: rabbitmq

I need to get the mapping of queues to the ip of the consumers using rabbit mq ctl.

In the UI, i can see this in the consumers tag which gives me the IP and the port.

Using rabbit mq ctl
list_queues    -> gives me the queue and channel name

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues    
q1  <rabbit@sg-rabbitmq-0.1.32026.83>
```

list_consumers -> gives me the list of consumers for queues with the channel ids

```
rabbitmqctl list_consumers
q1  <rabbit@sg-rabbitmq-0.1.23140.1150> amq.ctag-efPo6z_2JPGTP_Rt02yjdA true    1   []
```

list_channels  -> gives me the list of channels

```
rabbitmqctl list_channels  pid connection number user vhost transactional
<rabbit@sg-rabbitmq-0.1.23140.1150> <rabbit@sg-rabbitmq-0.1.31144.1148> 6   admin   /   false
```

How do i get the connection and ip for which this channel is created ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, need to pass the connection parameters in list_channels

```
rabbitmqctl list_channels pid connection name number
<rabbit@sg-rabbitmq-0.1.23140.1150> <rabbit@sg-rabbitmq-0.1.31144.1148> 52.187.117.61:1232 -> 10.3.110.215:5672 (6) 6
```

Using the connection to grep against the connections gives the ip details

```
 rabbitmqctl list_connections pid name  | grep "rabbit@sg-rabbitmq-0.1.31144.1148"
<rabbit@sg-rabbitmq-0.1.31144.1148> 1.2.3.4:1232 -> 10.10.10.215:5672
```

Where rabbit@sg-rabbitmq-0.1.31144.1148 is the connection id.